# how to know if my linq query returns null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, linq

I have this linq query :

```
var myQuery = from Q in myDataContext
          select Q.Name
```

and when I try to do this :
    listView.ItemsSource = myQuery

it sometimes throws an exception because there are no elements in `myQuery`

I tried many ways like : `if(myQuery.count!=0)`  or `if(myQuery.Any())` 
but nothing worked , so how can I determine if my Query return null ?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing worked"? What error did you get? Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: @Guffa said right you have missed a table name.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can realise the result as a list:

```
var myQuery = (from Q in myDataContext select Q.Name).ToList();
```

Now you can check the number of items:

```
if (myQuery.Count > 0) ...
```

You could also use the `Count()` method on the original query, but then you would be running the query twice, once to count the items, and once to use them.

Comment: var myAppointmentsQuery = from myApp in DC.Appointments
                                      where (myApp.Appointment_Date == datePicker_showAppointmentDate.SelectedDate && myApp.Doctor.Name == comboBox_showAppointmentsDoctor.SelectedItem.ToString())
                                      select new { myApp.Patient.Name, myApp.Appointment_Time };
            if (myAppointmentsQuery.Count()!=0)  
            {
                listView_appointmentsList.ItemsSource = myAppointmentsQuery;
            }

Comment: @Mouayad: That should be working. You should however get the input from the UI fields and validate them before using them in the query. Invalid input is the most likely reason that the code would fail sometimes.

Comment: Could you use  myQuery.Any() instead of  myQuery.Count>0 ?

Comment: @EGP: Yes, but that would just be a detour to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ queries should never return null and you should not get an exception if the result is empty. You probably have an error in your code.

It looks like the code you posted is missing the table name. Are you sure that the code you posted is the code that is giving you problems?

Comment: i think he's describing a case where the result is 0 records
later calling a ToList<Type>() on that query would throw an exception.

Comment: @eranotzer: Why would calling ToList throw an exception? I am fairly certain that it would just return a list with zero elements.

Comment: i need to check this out again ,
but i remember a similar case that happened to me when calling the generic ToList<T>()  on 0 results threw an exception.
i'll get back to you on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can convert it to list and then check the count

```
var result = (from Q in myDataContext select Q.Name).ToList();
if(result.Count > 0)
{
 // Perform some operation
}
```

or you can do a null check as by default the linq queries return null instead of an empty list.

```
var result = (from Q in myDataContext select Q.Name);
if(result != null)
{
 // Perform some operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var myQuery = from Q in myDataContext
if(myQuery != null ) 
{
  // TO SOME THING HERE
}
```

or u can additionally check that like if there is list in result

```
var myQuery = from Q in myDataContext
if(myQuery != null && myQuery.Count > 0  ) 
{
  // TO SOME THING HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to check there is null(no items) in list use Any() instead of count()

var myQuery = (from Q in myDataContext select Q.Name).ToList();
Now you can check the number of items:

if (myQuery.Any()) ...