# How do i check if my Linq query produced any result?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

Hi guys I am using entity framework, I am facing some problem while checking if my linq returned any results, if it returns any result I want to use it as a data source, the following is the code please have a look:

```
    var dbContext = new DBEntities();
    try
    {
        var linQuery = from cq in dbContext.tblCharacteristics
                        where cq.CharacteristicID.Equals(combobox1.SelectedText)
                        select new
                        {
                            CharacteristicIDs = cq.CharID,
                            CharacteristicNames = cq.CharName
                        };

        if (linQuery.Any()) //Also tried with linQuery.Count() != 0
        {
            lbChaKeyValues.DataSource = linQuery;
            lbChaKeyValues.DisplayMember = "CharacteristicNames";
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        dbContext.Dispose();
    }
```

I am getting following error : **"DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types."**

Comment: What is `charQuery`? What is it defined as?

Comment: @KMan, a valid question, though i don't think the problem, at least this particular one is with that variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to know if my linq query returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132514/how-to-know-if-my-linq-query-returns-null)

Comment: @KMan thanks for pointing it out i meant linQuery not charQuery, Updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF CharacteristicID is an integer type, the comparison won't work. Instead try

```
   var inputFromUser = Int32.Parse( combobox1.SelectedText );

   var linQuery = from cq in dbContext.tblCharacteristics
                    where cq.CharacteristicID == inputFromUser
                    select new
                    {
                        CharacteristicIDs = cq.CharID,
                        CharacteristicNames = cq.CharName
                    };
```

Incidentally `.Any()` is the correct way to test for search results. And if you're not going to use the return results, there's no need to project the data into an anonymous type. Just use `select true` or `select cq` which allows the optimizer to use the best index in the DB.

Comment: seems like a tryparse might be more robust as we're dealing with user input here