# How do I know if my linq will return a useable object or a null

Tags: linq, return-value

I am working on a web service.  I am using linq to query a database.  Seemingly simple, but I've run into an issue.  Here is my code for reference:

```
List<Comment> res = new List<Comment>();

using (ApplicationHistoryEntities ahe = new ApplicationHistoryEntities())
{
     res = (from columns in ahe.Comments
        where columns.NetforumId == actionuniqueid
            select columns).ToList();
}
```

If I have no entries in the database, will my .ToList() throw an error?  I could deploy it, and just try it out but I want to know more about the mechanism that my linq is using.  If ahe.Comments database has no rows... what will the (from...) section return?

I could just add a null reference check, use dynamics etc but I want to really understand it.

I found this Q: [how to know if my linq query returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132514/how-to-know-if-my-linq-query-returns-null) but it seems like all of the answers are in conflict on how it really should be done...

example answers:

1. Either you can convert it to list and then check the count
2. Best approach is to check there is null(no items) in list use Any() instead of count()
3. LINQ queries should never return null and you should not get an exception if the result is empty. You probably have an error in your code.
4. You can realise the result as a list then check the items.

You can see why I question how it works.

Edit:
Final code looks like this:

```
List<Comment> res;
using (ApplicationHistoryEntities ahe = new ApplicationHistoryEntities())
{
    res = ahe.Comments?.Where(rowItem => rowItem.NetforumId == actionuniqueid).ToList() ??
          new List<Comment>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: If no rows in `ahe.Comments`, the `.ToList()` will not throw any error. Yah you can use that `.Any()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example:

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
var test1 = test.Where(x => x == "a").ToList();
```

If `test` exists but is empty the query returns an empty list. If `test` is `null` the query throws an error. So you can adapt the query as follows

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
test = null;
var test1 = test?.Where(x => x == "a") ?? new List<string>().ToList();
```

The query is now 'safe'. Both of the above examples return an empty list i.e. `test1.Count()` will return zero but will be usable.

You can also look at the definitions of [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) and [ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for the academic answer.  I appreciate it.